# how to plot y-axis points between specific intervals of x-axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, errorbar

I have x and y values. The x-axis values lie between 65 to 79, which are divided into three bins i.e., 65-69, 70-74, 75-80. I have computed the mean and standard deviation for each bin. The data is shown in the figure.

[image]

I want to plot the mean and std as error bars in the respective bin of the x-axis. The resultant plot is also shown in the following figure. Please if anyone knows, can help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this ?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xValues = [67, 72, 77]
yValues = [67, 72, 77]
xErrorValues = [1.6, 1.6, 1.6]
yErrorValues = [1.6, 1.6, 1.6]
plt.scatter(xValues, yValues, zorder = 2)
plt.errorbar(xValues, yValues, xerr = xErrorValues, yerr = yErrorValues,
  fmt = 'none', capsize = 10, ecolor = 'red', zorder = 1)
plt.xlim(60, 90)
plt.ylim(60, 90)
plt.show()
```

[image]